# Can you use the Wii Classic Control for the Wii version of Destroy All Humans?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, destroy-all-humans

I find the controller layout of *Destroy All Humans* for the Wii to be too annoying to play for long, using the IR sensor to control the camera is just a pain.

I really liked using dual analog sticks to control movement and the camera in the X-Box version.  I have noticed that the classic controller has dual analog sticks.  Will it work with most games, or only with games that explicitly say they will work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only certain Wii games can utilize the Classic Controller, and the ones that can will explicitly say on the packaging. Destroy All Humans isn't on [this Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wii_games_that_use_the_Classic_Controller) of Classic Controller compatible games, so I don't believe it would work with the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to " *Destroy All Humans: Big Willy Unleashed!* " ?  As far as I know, it's the only game in the series available for the Wii.

---

If so, I can tell you definitively that it is not supported with the Classic Controller.  I own the game, and didn't have any luck with a Classic Controller either.   :(